# How to make the autocomplete term widget (tagging) case-sensitive?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, ajax

I notice that although the Autocomplete term widget (tagging) happily autocompletes terms with their right letter case, after saving the terms are changed to lower case. E.g. I have two tags "Drupal" and "drupal" and although I autocomplete "Drupal" and save the node, what gets saved is "drupal".

Is there a way to force case-sensitivity for this widget -- or vocabulary?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Termcase](https://drupal.org/project/termcase) module, It will do that.

> It prevents users to use different cases on terms. With termcase you
>   can make sure all terms in a vocabulary begin with an uppercase or
>   that they are all formatted to lowercase.

[image]

There are five options available:

- No formatting
- Ucfirst: convert the first character of the term to uppercase
- Lowercase: convert all characters of the term to lowercase
- Uppercase: convert all characters of the term to uppercase
- Propercase: convert the first character of earch word to uppercase

You can define these settings per vocabulary. The module even enables you to **update** all existing terms in a vocabulary and select whether or not you want to convert synonyms as well.